# Python pip install Not finding requierements versions

Tags: python-3.x, pip

I am using Python 3.7, pip version: 10.0.1, OS: Windows 10

In CMD i am installing dependencies with the command:

```
Python -m pip install requirements.txt
```

But it show this message:

Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement requirements.txt (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for requirements.txt

requirements.txt contains:

```
#Flask framework 

Flask

#Flask packages 
Flask-RESTful 
Flask-JWT 
Flask-SQLAlchemy 
Flask-Mail
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're missing `-r` flag in your `pip install` command

```
python -m pip install -r requirements.txt
```