# Cannot install this manim lib for python

Tags: python-3.x, manim

I'm trying to install *manim*, (see here: https://github.com/3b1b/manim). I'm using python version 3.7.7. I've followed the steps of this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZltiKHFWmv8 until I tried to install the requirements.txt (https://github.com/3b1b/manim/blob/master/requirements.txt). I get this error on the terminal:

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement requirements.txt (from versions: none)
>
> ERROR: No matching distribution found for requirements.txt

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python pip install Not finding requierements versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51275819/python-pip-install-not-finding-requierements-versions)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure you used the `-r` argument in the command, so you do `pip3 install -r requirements.txt`

Answer (score 0):

I tried installing it from https://github.com/3b1b/manim as well, didn't work. Then I stumbled across Manim's community version (https://github.com/ManimCommunity/manim). It is easier to set up and has great documentation. It worked like a charm for me.